# Trying to install Wordpress on Laravel Forge

Tags: php, wordpress, forge

I added wordpress using laravel forge, and I got:

> This site can’t be reached

I know that my domain is pointing to correct server. Because I can ping it. So the problem should be on Forge side.

I'm not sure what the `Web Directory` should be for wordpress.

I have tried: `/`, `/public`, `/wp_content`

And I have run out of ideas. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: `/` should be enough :) is there anything in the server logs?

Comment: @Marcis, did you build the wordpress website locally and deploy that to Laravel Forge? If so, would love to know how you did that. Trying to find a good tutorial on how to deploy Wordpress to Laravel Forge by using local project uploaded to Git. But couldn't find any. Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, I installed straight to forge. I think it is not supposed to build on locally first and then using forge